# UIImageView draw with delay

Tags: ios, concurrency, uiimageview

I got a problem with drawing on `UIImageView` with delay. I got method `[className drawPoint:(CGPoint)point]` (this method can draw point and it works fine )

Next I want to draw 3 points from array in circle with a 1 sec delay, and if I use `[self performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:]` I will see all 3 points on `UIImageView` after 3 seconds delay. But I want it to draw point1 then after 1 second point2 and then after 1 second point3.

I've also tried to play with `dispatch_async` but didn't get desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
 [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(drawThreePoints) withObject:nil];
```

The drawThreePoints method:

```
-(void)drawThreePoints{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(drawPoint:) withObject:POINT1 waitUntilDone:NO];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(drawPoint:) withObject:POINT2 waitUntilDone:NO];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(drawPoint:) withObject:POINT3 waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

The drawPoint: method:

```
-(void)drawPoint:(CGPoint)point{
     [className drawPoint:point];
}
```

UPD: Or, if points are from array, you can do it in the loop, of course :)

Comment: thanks xexe! you make my day ) now I'll try to do it with dispatch_async

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stagger the drawing of a view, `drawRect` is not the place to do it.  A better solution would be to draw everything you want to draw in `drawRect` (or separate out your staggered elements into different views each with their own `drawRect`) and to toggle the hidden property with `UIView`'s class method `animateWithDuration`.

Comment: I would advise you to use the `animateWithDuration`. The way you tried is not very convenient.